# Discover why GoDC won't start on Mac

Tags: macos, go-cd

I'm trying to run [GoCD](https://www.gocd.org) on MacOS (10.12) for testing purposes. When I run both the server and the client apps, they do not provide any GUI output (they should show progress bars or a host configuration) and they quit a couple of seconds after starting.

When I try to run the apps from Terminal as:

```
/Applications/Go\ Server.app/Contents/MacOS/go-server
```

I get the following output:

> Got directory: /Users/taatyyu1/Library/Application Support/Go Server  [It exists]

and then the app quits.

How can I discover what is the issue of the apps not starting properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logs of the apps are available in

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Go\ Server/osx-app.log
```

and

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Go\ Agent/osx-app.log
```

They contain the information from apps starting up and you can use them to figure out what goes wrong